# What does passing the base 3 test mean here?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have got this one:

Let $n$ be a positive odd integer passing the base 3 test, i.e. $3^n\equiv 3\pmod n$. Prove that $\frac{3^n-1}{2}$ also passes the base 3 test.

My attempt:

$3^n\equiv 3\pmod n$

$\Rightarrow 3^n-1\equiv 2\pmod n$

$\Rightarrow \frac{3^n-1}{2}\equiv 1 \pmod n$

Thus, $3^{\frac{3^n-1}{2}}\equiv3^1\pmod n$

Is that what it means to pass the base 3 test for $\frac{3^n-1}{2}$?

Comment: It seems that you assume that if $n \equiv m \bmod p$, then $a^m \equiv a^n \bmod p$. But this isn't true. For example, $2 \equiv 7 \bmod 5$, but $3^2 \equiv 4 \bmod 5$ and $3^7 \equiv 2 \bmod 5$.

Comment: @FirdousAhmadMala I believe you've misunderstood the question somewhat. It seems that any particular odd positive integer, call it $m$, passes "the base $3$ test" if $3^m \equiv 3 \pmod{m}$. The question states that if $m = n$ passes this test, then prove that $m = \frac{3^n-1}{2}$ also passes, i.e., $\frac{3^n-1}{2}$ is an odd positive integer and that $3^{\frac{3^n-1}{2}} \equiv 3 \pmod{\frac{3^n-1}{2}}$.

Comment: @davidlowryduda Thanks a lot. You are correct.

Comment: @JohnOmielan You seem correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simpler algebra, let

$$r = \frac{3^n-1}{2} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note the problem is actually asking to prove that, given $n$ passes the test, then $r$ also passes the "base $3$ test", i.e., $r$ is a positive, odd integer and $3^r \equiv 3 \pmod{r}$.

Since $n$ is a positive, odd integer, then $r \ge 1$ and $3^n \equiv (-1)^n \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, so $3^n-1 \equiv 2 \pmod{4} \; \; \to \; \; \frac{3^n-1}{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$, i.e., $r$ is a positive, odd integer too. From \eqref{eq1A}, we also have

$$3^n \equiv 1 \pmod{r} \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Next, let

$$m = \operatorname{ord}_{r}(3) \; \; \to \; \; 3^m \equiv 1 \pmod{r} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

where $\operatorname{ord}_{r}(3)$ is the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $3$ modulo $r$. Since $n$ passes the "base $3$ test", and \eqref{eq2A} shows that $m \mid n$, we have

$$3^n \equiv 3 \pmod{n} \; \; \to \; \; 3^n \equiv 3 \pmod{m} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

As you've already basically done, $3^n - 1 \equiv 2 \pmod{m} \; \to \; r = \frac{3^n-1}{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{m}$. This means there's an integer $k$ where $r = km + 1$. Thus, using this and \eqref{eq3A}, we get that

$$3^r \equiv 3^{km + 1} \equiv \left(3^m\right)^k(3) \equiv 3 \pmod{r} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

This proves that $r = \frac{3^n-1}{2}$ also passes the "base $3$ test".